# CAdES signature with win32 low level message apis

Tags: c++, cryptography, asn.1

I am trying to use the low level message functions to create a CAdES-BES compliant signature.

The signature has to be in proper PKCS#7 format along with four signed attributes present.

The first two, type and hash are automatically put but the crypto library.

The third one is the time of the message. I was able to put this using CryptEncodeObject and szOID_RSA_signingTime
"1.2.840.113549.1.9.5".

The fourth one is the signing certificate, which OID's is not supported by the crypto API, 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47.

To be able to add this manually I have to know how CryptEncodeObject works internally, and the sort of structure to encode:

```
SigningCertificateV2 ::=  SEQUENCE {
certs        SEQUENCE OF ESSCertIDv2,
policies     SEQUENCE OF PolicyInformation OPTIONAL
}


ESSCertIDv2 ::=  SEQUENCE {
hashAlgorithm           AlgorithmIdentifier
       DEFAULT {algorithm id-sha256},
certHash                 Hash,
issuerSerial             IssuerSerial OPTIONAL
}

Hash ::= OCTET STRING

IssuerSerial ::= SEQUENCE {
 issuer                   GeneralNames,
 serialNumber             CertificateSerialNumber
}
```

And more structures that have to be included before it's completed.

I *could* try to use an ASN.1 compiler to build the whole thing, then a DER encoder to encode it, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, you have to use an ASN.1 compiler and then encode signed attributes with the CMS.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1256991/AdES-An-implementation-of-CAdES-for-Windows-in-Cpl